# reactjs and rendering plain HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

First of all I'm totally new to react so I'm not sure if my code is already written the "react way".

So far I've created a couple of react classes which render a Bootstrap Modal. To set the initial states I call an Ajax function within the `componentsDidMount` function. This works fine until I try to insert plain HTML into the modal body.

The server request works fine and I get plain HTML code in my `this.state.data.content` but if I try to insert this into the modal body I receive following error:

> Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__html}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I even doing the right thing here?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/babel">

    var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
    var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
    var ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;


    var L5fmHeaderButton = React.createClass({

        render: function() {
            var iconClass = "glyphicon " + this.props.buttonIcon;
            return(
                <button onClick={this.props.onClick} className="lfm-Modal-Button">
                    <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                    {this.props.buttonText}
                </button>
            );
        }
    });

    var L5fmModalBody = React.createClass({

        rawMarkup: function() {
            return { __html: this.props.content };
        },

        render: function() {

            return(
                <Modal.Body>
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}
                </Modal.Body>
            );
        }

    });

    var L5fmModal = React.createClass({

        getInitialState : function() {
            return {
                data : []
            };
        },

        componentDidMount: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'L5fm/setInitialState',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.setState({data: data});
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(this.state.data);
                }.bind(this),
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                }.bind(this)
            });
        },

        changeDirectory : function() {
            if (this.state.privateDir) {
                this.setState({privateDir: false});
            }
            else {
                this.setState({privateDir: true});
            }
        },

        render: function() {

            if(this.state.data.privateDir) {
                var browseIcon = "glyphicon-folder-open";
                var browseText = "browse all files";
            }
            else {
                var browseIcon = "glyphicon-briefcase";
                var browseText = "browse private files";
            }

            return(

                <Modal {...this.props} bsSize="large" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <div className="header-button-group">
                            <L5fmHeaderButton buttonIcon="glyphicon-cloud-upload" buttonText="upload" />
                            <L5fmHeaderButton buttonIcon="glyphicon-list" buttonText="list View" />
                            <L5fmHeaderButton onClick={this.changeDirectory} buttonIcon={browseIcon} buttonText={browseText} />
                        </div>
                </Modal.Header>
                    <L5fmModalBody content={this.state.data.content}/>
                </Modal>
            );
        }

    });


    var App = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { lgShow: false };
        },
        render: function() {
            let lgClose = () => this.setState({ lgShow: false });

            return (
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                       <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={()=>this.setState({ lgShow: true })}>
                           Launch large demo modal
                       </Button>

                       <L5fmModal show={this.state.lgShow} onHide={lgClose} />
                    </ButtonToolbar>
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("modal"));

</script>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to close the `<Modal.Body>` tag? I think the code where you set the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}` should be a property of the Modal.Body rather than a "child"

Comment: This is how [ReactBootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) has done its markup. But you are right that in this case I need an additional `<div>` tag to get it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as it seems, you are missing a [div-tag](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) where you wish to render your raw html

considering changing the Modal.Body code like this

```
var L5fmModalBody = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function() {
        return { __html: this.props.content };
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <Modal.Body>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
            </Modal.Body>
        );
    }
});
```

otherwise the rendering gets broken because your markup cannot really be set as a child on the [Modal.Body](https://github.com/jquense/react-bootstrap-modal/blob/master/src/Body.jsx) element